# Twitter feed hashtags on android

Tags: android, twitter

I want to make twitter feed hashtag on my app. i just follow tutorial in this web : http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/05/android-programming-tutorial-a-simple-twitter-feed-reader/ but i have error at "for(Object t : arr)" the warning is "can only iterate over an array....." how to solve this?

```
public class Tweet {
public String username;
public String message;
public String image_url;
public Tweet(String username, String message, String url) {
this.username = username;
this.message = message;
this.image_url = url;
}

public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets(String searchTerm, int page) {
String searchUrl =
"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@"
+ searchTerm + "&rpp=100&page=" + page;
ArrayList tweets =
new ArrayList();

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler =
new BasicResponseHandler();

String responseBody = null;
try {
responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
} catch(Exception ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject jsonObject = null;
JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

try {
Object obj = parser.parse(responseBody);
jsonObject=(JSONObject)obj;
}catch(Exception ex){
Log.v("TEST","Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}

JSONArray arr = null;

try {
Object j = jsonObject.get("results");
arr = (JSONArray)j;
} catch(Exception ex){
Log.v("TEST","Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
}

for(Object t : arr) {
Tweet tweet = new Tweet(
((JSONObject)t).get("from_user").toString(),
((JSONObject)t).get("text").toString(),
((JSONObject)t).get("profile_image_url").toString()
);
tweets.add(tweet);
}

return tweets;
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate through the JSONArray but you can't use

```
For(object t: arr) {
```

For JSONArrays. Replace that line with:

```
For (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```